# How to change architectures in static libraries?

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, static-libraries, arm64

I have several framework statics libraries (.a files). When i call `lip -info filename.a` upon those files the terminal tells me that the architecture arm64 is not there. However to comply with the new Apple regulation stating that the apps must work with arm64 i need to add that architecture to the static library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to convert the architecture of an existing library.  You'll need to go back to the original source and recompile it with the new architecture added.